# Error setting up OpenFrameworks Eclipse ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, openframeworks

I'm getting an error when I try to set up OF with Android in Eclipse with the ADT plugin. I've followed the guide on the Open Frameworks website. Below is the last part of the console output when I try to compile the Empty example:

```
compressing and copying resources from bin/data into res
cd /Users/sidatre/Google Drive/Scripts and Programs/OpenFrameworks/android/examples/android/androidEmptyExample/; \
    if [ -d "bin/data" ]; then \
        mkdir -p res/raw; \
        rm res/raw/google scripts and androidemptyexampleresources.zip; \
        if [ "darwin-x86_64" = "windows" ]; then \
            echo "Windows Platform. Running Zip..."; \
            cmd //c ..\\..\\..\\libs\\openFrameworksCompiled\\project\\android\\windows\\zip -r ./res/raw/google scripts and androidemptyexampleresources.zip ./bin/data/ && exit; \
        else \
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /Users/sidatre/Google: No such file or directory
            cd bin/data; \
            zip -r ../../res/raw/google scripts and androidemptyexampleresources.zip *; \
            cd ../..; \
        fi; \
    fi
copying debugging binaries for armv5 armv7 neon x86
create gdb.setup for armeabi
create gdb.setup for armeabi-v7a
create gdb.setup for x86
creating Android.mk and Application.mk
#@echo updating ofAndroidLib project
#@cd ../../../addons/ofxAndroid/ofAndroidLib; \
    #if [ "darwin-x86_64" = "windows" ]; then \
    #   cmd //c /Users/sidatre/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android.bat update project --target android-17 --path .; \
    #else \
    #   /Users/sidatre/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android update project --target android-17 --path .; \
    #fi
#@echo updating current project
#@cd /Users/sidatre/Google Drive/Scripts and Programs/OpenFrameworks/android/examples/android/androidEmptyExample/; \
    #if [ "darwin-x86_64" = "windows" ]; then \
    #   cmd //c /Users/sidatre/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android.bat update project --target android-17 --path .; \
    #else \
    #   /Users/sidatre/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android update project --target android-17 --path .; \
    #fi
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `Scripts'.  Stop.
make: *** [Release] Error 2
```

Where is the `Scripts` make target defined? I never created such a target.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the issue was with my folder structure, as the parent folder was called `Scripts and Programs` and the spaces between the words was interfering with the `make` process. Renaming the folder to `ScriptsAndPrograms` fixed my issue.